# Why are the Leviathans in Supernatural humans?

Tags: supernatural

I understand that they didn't have the budget to make a bunch of massive creatures for the boys to fight, but is that the only reason? Maybe the budget? Maybe the fact it had to be a realistic fight for the boys? Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The plan of the Leviathans and in particular of their leader, was to infiltrate human society. This can only be achieved if they look human, so even if their original shape was a black goo or something, they took human forms.

Specifically, their leader took the persona of

> Dick Roman an American businessman.

Comment: But could the not have just consumed everything in earth, heaven, hell, and purgatory? And been well fed for a while?

Comment: @Khaos, because "a while" is relative. Why gorge and eat everything when you can farm your food source and eat forever?